# Is it possible to serve static files in the Google Compute Instance from a Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am about to setup a Load Balancer with a bucket as CDN for my image files. The part I am not sure about is how to copy the images/ to the bucket. There is Fuse and gsutil. What is the best way? I am only familiar with other CDNs that automates this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Storage FUSE is an adapter that allows you to mount a bucket as a file system, while gsutil is a command line tool.

The documentation could help you to find out if Cloud Storage FUSE will be suitable for you because there are some [comparisons between using Cloud Storage FUSE and a regular file system](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#notes). It's stated, for example, that uploading many files to Cloud Storage FUSE should be as fast as using gsutil to upload to a Cloud Storage bucket, but individual uploads to Cloud Storage FUSE could take longer due to the higher latency associated with the tool.

The same documentation also has some instructions on [getting started with Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using).